# How to ignore safe area for a background with a linear gradient and image in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a VStack like this:

```
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            //some view
        }
        .background(
            ZStack{
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(
                    colors: [
                        .yellow_500,
                        .yellow_500,
                        .yellow_500,
                        .yellow_50
                    ]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.top])
                
                
                Image(R.image.home_bg_try.name)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.top])

            }
//                .offset(y: -20)
        )
    }
```

I want the image to be displayed without considering the safe area, which currently results in a white space appearing at the top, as shown in this image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/knRdm.png).

I attempted to fix this issue by adding an offset, but I noticed that the height of the white space varies across different models.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Your background won't take the entire `View` unless your `VStack` does as well. Does the `VStack` cover the entire frame?

Answer (score 0):

`background` never exceeds the size of the `View` it is applied to. So if your `VStack` doesn't cover the safe area, any background applied to it won't do so either, even if the background has an `ignoresSafeArea` modifier applied to it.

You can however, use a `ZStack` instead, which will size itself based on its largest element, which in this case will be your safe area ignoring background.

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    background

    VStack{
      //some view
    }
  }
}

private var background: some View {
  ZStack {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(
      colors: [
        .yellow_500,
        .yellow_500,
        .yellow_500,
        .yellow_50
      ]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.top])

    Image(R.image.home_bg_try.name)
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFill()
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
      .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: [.top])
  }
}
```